# Java Socket Communication "deadlock"

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, deadlock

Hi I am trying to implement server operating with multiply clients
The problem is that the server does not receive the message from inputstream and wait until it happen. if the client don't close the stream after writing to it the server will continue to wait. After the client send the message, he try to read from the inputstream waiting for response, but the server is waiting for the request. So.. deadlock

This is my client class

```
public class Client implements Runnable{

...

@Override
public void run() {

    BufferedReader is = null;
    BufferedWriter os = null;

    try(Socket socket = new Socket(address.getHostName(), address.getPort());){

        String request = String.format("%s-%d-%s",this.destination, this.desiredPlace, this.paymentMethod.toString());
        os = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        pw.write(request);
        pw.flush();
// if I close the stream here the request will be send, but this will close the socket so the I will not receive response.

        String response;
        while ((response = is.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(response);
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this is my server class

```
 public void perform() throws IOException, DestionationProcessingException, InterruptedException {
    try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);) {
        StandalonePayDesk offLinePayDesk = new StandalonePayDesk(ticketManager);
        this.threadPool.submit(offLinePayDesk);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler(this.threadPool, offLinePayDesk, this.ticketManager);
            handler.process(socket);
        }
    }
}
```

and RequestHandler class for processing each client

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)) {

        writer.println("hello");
        writer.flush();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] lineTokens = line.split("-");
              ...
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pw.write(request);
```

Your client is writing a request but not a line. Your server is reading a line, with `readLine()`, and will block until the line terminator arrives, which is never, so it will never send a reply, so your client will never receive it, so it will block forever.

Change the above to:

```
pw.println(request);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it